# Vehicle detection, count and classification in Python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, blob, background-subtraction, simplecv

I have to ultimately count the total number of vehicles in a video, distinguish between cars and trucks and color of the vehicles detected. I am using OpenCV, Python and SimpleCV for this. What I have done so far is:
1. Background subtraction
2.used find.Blobs() to find the blobs

based on the size of the blob, I can distinguish between cars and trucks. However, as I am finding the number of blobs on the foreground mask, all the blobs are white. So my question is how can I find out the color of the vehicles detected?

Comment: What if one vehicle is closer than the other?  It would be bigger, so how would you know if it's a truck or a car?

Comment: The truck is considerable larger in the video I have. So that isn't an issue with my video.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using Python or SimpleCV with OpenCV, but I assume you have something that corresponds to a Mat for each frame of the video.  If you can get the initial color version of this Mat along with the non-color mask, you can map the coordinates of the blobs into the color Mat, and then do color thresholds in those areas.  Look into contours, bounding boxes, and HSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assuming that the vehicles are mainly one colour, therefore you are looking for the mean colour of each blob, no?
This should draw a rectangle around each blob of width 3, with the rectangle colour being the mean colour.

Feel free to optimise :)

```
for blob in blobs:
    a=blob.meanColor()
    mc=(int(a[0]), int(a[1]), int(a[2]))
    rect=blob.boundingBox()
    img.drawRectangle(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3], mc, 3)
img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting approach is to use OpenCV HOG + SVM classifier to detect vehicles. Check out this blog:
https://medium.com/@priya.dwivedi/automatic-vehicle-detection-for-self-driving-cars-8d98c086b161#.6x2k4szf5

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”